# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060057

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

Please let me know where I am going wrong to get the error because i ma creating an app which is using recyclerview i have one image and one text and one imagebutton in my recyclerview's item layout . but it is giving me error when i am setting image on iamgebutton in onBindviewholder method

this is my error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                        Process: com.example.anonymous.recycleview, PID: 1008
>                                                                                        android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060057
>   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2558)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:85)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:94)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.example.anonymous.recycleview.RecycleAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecycleAdapter.java:45)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.example.anonymous.recycleview.RecycleAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecycleAdapter.java:17)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6482)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6515)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5458)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5724)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3962)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1197)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
>                                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
>                                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:443)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
>                                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
>                                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
>                                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
>                                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
>                                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
>                                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
>                                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3193)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2667)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2368)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1438)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.ja

code of my mainActivity
    package com.example.anonymous.recycleview;

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyClerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<item> i = new ArrayList<>();
        int images[]=
                {
                        R.drawable.icon_1,
                        R.drawable.icon_2,
                        R.drawable.icon_3,
                        R.drawable.icon_4,
                        R.drawable.icon_5,
                        R.drawable.icon_6,
                        R.drawable.icon_7,
                        R.drawable.icon_8,
                };

       for (int j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            item t = new item("this is item",images[j],R.drawable.delete);
            i.add(t);
        }

        recyClerView=findViewById(R.id.li);
       adapter= new RecycleAdapter(i);
       recyClerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyClerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }
}
```

code of recyclerAdapter class

```
    package com.example.anonymous.recycleview;

    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    /**
     * Created by Anonymous on 11/25/2017.
     */

    public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.holderclas>
    {

        private ArrayList<item> i;
        public RecycleAdapter(ArrayList<item> i)
        {
            this.i=i;
            for(int y=0;y<i.size();y++)
            {
                System.out.println(i.get(y).getImageButton());
            }

        }
        @Override
        public holderclas onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {

            View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
            holderclas h = new holderclas(view);


            return h;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(holderclas holder, final int position)
        {
            holder.detailOfItem.setText(i.get(position).getItemdetail());
            holder.image.setImageResource(i.get(position).getImage());
            holder.imagebutton.setImageResource(i.get(position).getImageButton());

            holder.imagebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    i.remove(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });


        }



        @Override
        public int getItemCount()
        {
            return i.size();
        }





        public static class holderclas extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            ImageView image;
            ImageButton imagebutton;
            TextView detailOfItem;
            public holderclas(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                imagebutton=itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
                detailOfItem=itemView.findViewById(R.id.detail);

            }
        }
    }
```

here is my item class which makes object to be shown in recyclerview

```
package com.example.anonymous.recycleview;

/**
 * Created by Anonymous on 11/25/2017.
 */

public class item
{
    private String Itemdetail;
    private int image;
    private int imageButton;

    public item(String Itemdetail,int image,int imageButton)
    {
        this.Itemdetail=Itemdetail;
        this.image=image;
        this.imageButton=imageButton;
    }

    public String getItemdetail()
    {
        return Itemdetail;
    }

    public void setItemdetail(String itemdetail)
    {
        Itemdetail = itemdetail;
    }

    public int getImage()
    {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public int getImageButton() {
        return imageButton;
    }

    public void setImageButton(int imageButton) {
        this.imageButton = imageButton;
    }
}
```

here is my manifetfile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.anonymous.recycleview">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.anonymous.recycleview"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

here is the xml of mainActivity

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.anonymous.recycleview.MainActivity">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="370dp"
            android:layout_height="438dp"
            android:id="@+id/li"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

        <Button

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="Add"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

here is the xml of each listitem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="74dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/detail"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.25"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
         />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.741"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/detail"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:layout_width="141dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="This is detail of item"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.018" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="356dp"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"></View>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please also share `item.xml`.

Comment: @azizbekian i have added my xml file for both item and mainActivity